# SELECT even if 0 entries

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

So the question I've been given is as follows:

For EACH academic, compute the total number of papers s/he has written. Output should include the acnum and total number of papers for each academic. In particular, an academic without any papers should have
zero(0) as number of papers in the output. You must use a JOIN operator.

The Query I have right now is below but the only issue is it doesn't select acnums that have 0 papers.

```
SELECT AUTHOR.ACNUM, COUNT(AUTHOR.PANUM)
FROM AUTHOR
INNER JOIN PAPER ON AUTHOR.PANUM = PAPER.PANUM
GROUP BY AUTHOR.ACNUM;
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hint: LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 3):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and count the papers instead.

```
SELECT AUTHOR.ACNUM, COUNT(PAPER.PANUM)
FROM AUTHOR
LEFT JOIN PAPER ON AUTHOR.PANUM = PAPER.PANUM
GROUP BY AUTHOR.ACNUM
```

Comment: For some reason I still don't see entries with 0 panums.

Comment: @Joshm102 Is this the full query you are executing? Do you have a `WHERE` clause with a condition against the `PAPER` table?

Comment: That's the full query, no where clause.

Comment: @Joshm102 Are you sure you have authors with no papers? Check it with `SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PAPER WHERE PAPER.PANUM = AUTHOR.PANUM)`

Comment: I looked in the data of my tables and checked and there are definitely 3 without them, but also that query doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Joshm102 it seems that you aren't checking your data correctly. Make sure that the exact same `PANUM` code does NOT exist on the `PAPER` table. If you still don't see it, edit your post with the data so we can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT AUTHOR.ACNUM,COUNT(AUTHOR.PANUM)
FROM AUTHOR
LEFT JOIN PAPER ON AUTHOR.PANUM = PAPER.PANUM
GROUP BY AUTHOR.ACNUM;
```

Comment: The coalesce is not needed